# retrieving image from database on a new Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, voyager

Hello I have created two projects on Laravel **one for Voyager package** and other **has my front end of my e commerce website**. I have stored my entries on my database Named "LaravelPro" through Voyager successfully, but Now I wish to **retrieve the stored data** on the project which has front end of my website **But I am unable to fetch the images on my front end** although the price and name of my products are fetched successfully on my front end.
Their is no image in my **Storage\public** folder.

**this is my controller**

```
class BakerysController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
    return view('main.kitchen.bakery')->with('bakerys',Bakery::all());
    }
}
```

**this my model**

```
class Bakery extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='bakerys';
}
```

**this is where I intend to display my image**

```
<img src={{  $bakery->bakeimage) }}alt="">
```

[this is my public folder on my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA5Bl.jpg)

the database I am using for the project is PHP my admin

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. "_the database I am using for the project is PHP my admin_" No it's not, phpMyAdmin is a GUI to manage your MySQL server/databases

Comment: @kerbh0lz I have added code for you can you sort it out please?